# Shortcode - Getting Categories appears on top of website

Tags: shortcode, categories

I tried using `ob_start` but still my categories query in the shortcode appears on top of the site and outside its container. any ideas what's wrong here?

```
function life_shortcode(){

$args = array('title_li' => '');
$mycats = wp_list_categories($args);

return '<div class="conmenu"><a class="salit" href="/lifestyle/"><i class="x-icon-home" data-x-icon=""></i></a><ul>' . $mycats . '</ul></div>';

}

add_action('wp_head', function() {

  add_shortcode( 'lifemenu', function() {
    ob_start();

    life_shortcode();

    return ob_get_clean();
  } );
}, 100 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You're running your `add_shortcode()` function in `wp_head`. You don't need to do that.
2. Your `life_shortcode()` function is returning a value, not echoing it. So it's not going to be caught by the output buffer and `ob_get_clean()` will return nothing.
3. `wp_list_categories()` is *echoing*, so is not going to be properly put into `$mycats` and is going to be output at the top of the page whenever your shortcode is used.

The proper way to organise this code would be:

```
function life_shortcode() {
    $args = array('title_li' => '', 'echo' => false);
    $mycats = wp_list_categories($args);

    return '<div class="conmenu"><a class="salit" href="/lifestyle/"><i class="x-icon-home" data-x-icon=""></i></a><ul>' . $mycats . '</ul></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'lifemenu', 'life_shortcode' );
```

Also note that I've passed the function name directly to `add_shortcode()`, rather than use an anonymous function that calls the original function. This way uses less code, and makes it easier for it to integrate with other plugins, if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the explaination Jacob.. now it makes total sense :)